# Rename class across all flavors

Tags: java, android-studio, automated-refactoring

I have android application which contains several build flavors.
In every flavor there are classes with same name but different code.
For example:

```
--main flavor
----BaseClassA
--first custom flavor
----CustomClassA extends BaseClassA
--second custom flavor
----CustomClassA extends BaseClassA
```

In android studio I can rename only within one flavor.
If I rename class within first flavor I would get:

```
--main flavor
----BaseClassNewName
--first custom flavor
----CustomClassNewName extends BaseClassNewName
--second custom flavor
----CustomClassA extends BaseClassA
```

**Is there any plugin or tool to rename class across all flavors?**

Global replace function works good, but it replaces only class names and keeps class file names.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, you can try the `rename` command. This is not really a 'refactoring tool', but may be working in combination with your global replace function.

`$ rename 's/oldname/newname/' flavor*/CustomClass`

Refer to this [Tutorial](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm) for more information and examples.